# How can I use regex to get all the characters after a specific character, e.g. comma (",")

Tags: javascript, regex

Need a Regex to get all characters after `,` (not including it) from a variable. This variable can contain for example

```
'SELECT___100E___7',24
'SELECT___100E___7',1
'SELECT___100E___7',286
'SELECT___100E___7',5147
```

Note: There can be any length of characters after the `,` in this variable.

An explanation of the regexp would be a added help for the novice :)

Edit: a javascript answer would be just as good

Comment: Which language are you using?  If you want a Java example, a Perl answer for example  would confuse you.

Comment: javascript/jQuery sorry forgot to mention. So something like this var result_val = $(this).attr('href').match(RegEX);

Comment: Why do you **absolutely** need regex ? This solution can easily be implement with basic string manipulation.

Comment: Meta-comment: If you come here from a google search, you are looking for Regex help, somewhat annoying to find lots of answers saying 'you don't need regex'

Comment: +up to what Andrew said

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You don't need regex to do this. Here's an example :

```
var str = "'SELECT___100E___7',24";
var afterComma = str.substr(str.indexOf(",") + 1); // Contains 24 //
```

Comment: Actually, no I do not absolutely need a Regex answer. I have changed my question to reflect this more clearly and your answer is quite clear and works.

Comment: This gets text after a word of any length: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44617843/4732117

Answer (score 62):

#### Short answer

Either:

- `,[\s\S]*$` or `,.*$` to match everything after the first comma (see explanation for which one to use); or
- `[^,]*$` to match everything after the last comma (which is probably what you want).

You can use, for example, `/[^,]*/.exec(s)[0]` in JavaScript, where *s* is the original string. If you wanted to use multiline mode and find all matches that way, you could use `s.match(/[^,]*/mg)` to get an array (if you have more than one of your posted example lines in the variable on separate lines).

#### Explanation

- `[\s\S]` is a character class that matches both whitespace and non-whitespace characters (i.e. all of them). This is different from `.` in that it matches newlines.
- `[^,]` is a negated character class that matches everything except for commas.
- `*` means that the previous item can repeat 0 or more times.
- `$` is the anchor that requires that the end of the match be at the end of the string (or end of line if using the /m multiline flag).

For the first match, the first regex finds the first comma `,` and then matches all characters afterward until the end of line `[\s\S]*$`, including commas.

The second regex matches as many non-comma characters as possible before the end of line. Thus, the entire match will be after the last comma.

Comment: you second answer worked but I decided to go with the non regex solution. Thanks for you effort!!!

Comment: I used this: [^/?]*$. At first I forgot to escape the ? with /  and it didn't work.

Answer (score 19):

```
[^,]*$
```

might do.  (Matches everything after the last comma).

Explanation: `[^,]` matches every character except for `,`.  The `*` denotes that the regexp matches any number of repetition of `[^,]`.  The `$` sign matches the end of the line.

Comment: This does not match everything after a `,` but anything except `,`. What if there is no `,`?

Comment: The examples in the original post suggested that there *is* a comma.  And the behaviour without a comma was not defined, so this should be fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
.+,(.+)
```

Explanation:

```
.+,
```

will search for everything before the comma, including the comma.

```
(.+)
```

will search for everything after the comma, and depending on your regex environment,

```
\1
```

is the reference for the first parentheses captured group that you need, in this example, everything after the comma.

Answer (score 5):

This matches a word from any length:

```
var phrase = "an important number comes after this: 123456";
var word = "this: ";
var number = phrase.substr(phrase.indexOf(word) + word.length);
// number = 123456
```

Comment: This thing definitely helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Another idea is to do `myVar.split(',')[1];`

For simple case, not using a regexp is a good idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the following:

```
new_string = your_string.split(',').pop().trim();
```

This is how it works:

- `split(',')` creates an array made of the different parts of `your_string`

(e.g. if the string is `"'SELECT___100E___7',24"`, the array would be `["'SELECT___100E___7'", "24"]`).

- `pop()` gets the last element of the array

(in the example, it would be `"24"`).

This would already be enough, but in case there might be some spaces (not in the case of the OP, but more in general), we could have:

- `trim()` that would remove the spaces around the string (in case it would be `" 24  "`, it would become simply `"24"`)

It's a simple solution and surely easier than a regexp.

Comment: A little bit of expanation might be called for. What are the pros and cons versus a regexp solution?

Comment: i didnt find any cons.. i find it easy becoz regex is usually not understandable

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this

```
var str = "'SELECT___100E___7',24";
    var res = str.split(',').pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
preg_match_all('@.*\,(.*)@', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

You can test it here: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

RegEx: `.*\,(.*)`

Same RegEx test here for JavaScript:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake for not including what language I wanted

Comment: You can still use the same RegEx

Answer (score 0):

`(?<=,).+`

A positive lookbehind on `,`

The group is followed by any character `.` with a quantifier `+` of one or more of them.