# Matching everything after the first comma in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am using java to do a regular expression match. I am using rubular to verify the match and ideone to test my code.

I got a regex from [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058923/get-all-characters-after-character) , and it matches the group as I want it to in rubular, but my implementation in java is not matching. When it prints 'value', it is printing the value of commaSeparatedString and not matcher.group(1) I want the captured group/output of println to be "v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso"

```
String commaSeparatedString = "Vtest7,v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso";
//match everything after first comma
String myRegex = ",(.*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myRegex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(commaSeparatedString);
 String value = "";
if (matcher.matches())
    value = matcher.group(1);
else
    value = commaSeparatedString;                     
System.out.println(value);
```

(edit: I left out that commaSeparatedString will not always contain 2 commas. Rather, it will always contain 0 or more commas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the regex is wrong. It should be:

```
String myRegex = "[^,]*,(.*)";
```

Comment: It need not be. You want to match whatever is after a comma, you don't need to match _all_ the input for that.

Comment: I was actually able to derive the regex that I need from this solution. I ended up using `[^,]*,(.*)`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have to solve it with regex, you can try this:

```
int size = commaSeparatedString.length();
value = commaSeparatedString.substring(commaSeparatedString.indexOf(",")+1,size);
```

Namely, the code above returns the substring which starts from the first comma's index.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I've omitted the simpler version. Thanks to one of the commentators, you can use this single line as well:

```
value = commaSeparatedString.substring( commaSeparatedString.indexOf(",") );
```

Comment: No need to apologies since simpler version eventually uses your little more complex version :)

Comment: good to know - I think I will use this approach for future simple matches

Answer (score 1):

You are yet another victim of Java's misguided regex method naming.

`.matches()` automatically anchors the regex at the beginning and end (which is in total contradiction with the very definition of "regex matching"). The method you are looking for is `.find()`.

However, for such a simple problem, it is better to go with @DelShekasteh's solution.

Comment: Note that this also means that your original regex is perfectly fine. No need to change it!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this like

```
    String commaSeparatedString = "Vtest7,v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso";

    System.out.println(commaSeparatedString.substring(commaSeparatedString.indexOf(",")+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with limited split

```
String[] spl = "Vtest7,v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso".split(",", 2);
if (spl.length == 2)
    System.out.println(spl[1]);
```

Byt IMHO [Del's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14264237/1393766) is best for your case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use replaceFirst

```
String commaSeparatedString = "Vtest7,v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso";
System.out.println(commaSeparatedString.replaceFirst(".*?,", ""));
```

prints

```
v123_gpbpvl-testpv1,v223_gpbpvl-testpv1-iso
```

or you could use the shorter but obtuse

```
System.out.println(commaSeparatedString.split(",", 2)[1]);
```