# Regex how to get what comes after a certain word in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
http://localhost:3000/?code=85b1a3645tgreg1f54221d8d9f54923b88ade29945yttrtgdg903
```

I am trying to get whatever comes after 'code=' from this string. How could I do this?

Comment: Why not parse the url with javascript instead of using a regex, and then for example use split?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use regex to get all the characters after a specific character, e.g. comma (",")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058923/how-can-i-use-regex-to-get-all-the-characters-after-a-specific-character-e-g-c)

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
code=(.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/V8IxoG/1).

---

In `JavaScript` this could be:

```js
let string = 'http://localhost:3000/?code=85b1a3645tgreg1f54221d8d9f54923b88ade29945yttrtgdg903';
let m = string.match(/code=(.+)/);
console.log(m[1]);
```

But it would possibly be more straight-forward to parse the url as it is and use the query part accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`str.match(/code=(.*)/)[1]` will do that for you.